# Suggestions for a Master thesis in option pricing models

Tags: options, volatility, garch

I am willing to do my Master Thesis about option pricing.
Do you have any suggestions? I would like it to be something simple, like comparing methods, e.g. compare ARCH and GARCH approaches for volatility estimates and their impact options pricing . Or this could be some empiriacl study using data from the Market. Any suggestions of something simple?
Please try to detail a little bit because I am a beginner in the subject - I've fully read Hull and I'm starting to read Schreve.
Thanks!

Comment: Frankly, just by reading Hull's is not  yet ready for a thesis on option pricing, unless you already have a good background in probability, statistics, or econometrics.

Comment: @Gordon yes, I have a good background in statistics. Would you have any suggestion of a subject for my master thesis?

Comment: I believe you need to discuss with your supervisor. Most of us are industry professionals.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In option pricing, the entire game is fitting the skew with a fairly robust model. All the research right now is in LSV (Local Stochastic Vol) Models. Fitting these is a challenge (with PDE or Particle Methods), maybe a study on that will be ideal if you're looking for a derivatives job after.

Alternately, you could also test ML techniques in obtaining the vol surface (or even estimating vol models)

Comment: Why do you say fitting these is a challenge? Jaeckel's hyphyp model (with a few adjustments to make it more flexible - ie time dependent params) can be diffused as a 2d pde for fitting, and works very nicely...

Comment: @Drew What is ML?

Comment: Machine Learning

Answer (score 1):

1. Fit GARCH to data.
2. Use obtained GARCH model and Monte Carlo simulation method for pricing options.
3. Compare speed of classical and quasi-Monte Carlo algorithms.